# Negation with positive meaning

Tags: negación

Can someone explain the grammar of "Lo necesito más que nada," "Te conozco mejor que nadie," "Es la mejor política nunca pensada en este país"? Why are negative words used here?

Comment: Apart from word order the English "There is nothing I need more than that", "There is nobody I know better than you." are similar. I am afraid I do not know the name of the grammatical construct which is why this is just a comment not an answer.

Comment: You are aware of the negative question in English, aren't you?

Comment: @WalterMitty No, I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @mdewey I just realized (and corrected my answer accordingly) that your translation "There is nobody I know better than you" corresponds to "Te conozco mejor que A nadie", where "nadie" is object. Without "a", "nadie" is the subject of the comparative clause: "There is nobody who knows you better than I do".

Comment: https://www.talkenglish.com/speaking/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=4284#:~:text=Negative%20Questions%201%20We%20use%20negative%20questions%20to,one%20negative%20question%20that%20is%20a%20little%20different.

Comment: @Gustavson Of course. Good job I only posted as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [NGLE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=OeNZoybAyXgYCYHd) (2009 edition, item 48.6o), comparative quantifiers of inequality are strong negative polarity inducers:

- Javier, **más** rumboso que **nunca**, pidió cuatro whiskies (Vargas Llosa, *Tía*).
- Nadie como él puede aborrecer la soledad de los unos y de los otros, la suya **menos** que la de **ninguno** (Díez, *Expediente*).
- Eso es **mejor** que **nada** (Ribera, *Sangre*).
- [...] entonces quizá **peor** que en **ningún** otro instante de la vida (Tusquets, *Mar*).

Curiously, in English we use neutral pronouns and adverbs in this case:

- Lo necesito más que nada (I need it more than **anything** else).
- Te conozco mejor que nadie (I know you better than **anybody** else).
- Es la mejor política nunca pensada en este país (It's the best policy **ever** conceived in this country).

However, as @mdewey said in a comment above, in subject or initial position the focus makes those words negative:

- There is **nothing** I need more.
- There is **nobody** who knows you better than I do.
- **Never** has a better policy been conceived in this country.

Comment: I found the corresponding section in the Manual de la NGLE, which helped me a lot. Thanks for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at *Nueva gramática de la lengua española: Manual*, 48.5.2d: "En cuanto que denotan la exclusión de individuos o grados, constituyen inductores negativos fuertes los cuantificadores comparativos de desigualdad [y] los superlativos."